# Object Null exception when checking if database exists with Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb nuget package > 1.62

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have the following query to check if an Azure DocumentDb database exists. This code functions currently with the SDK up to nuget package version 1.62, but throws a runtime null object exception in 1.63 and 1.7.

Is this the wrong way to query if a database exists or is there an issue in the later SDK releases?

Thanks

```
using (IReliableReadWriteDocumentClient dbClient = GetDocumentClient())
{
    // Check to verify a database with the id does not exist
    Database database = dbClient.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == databaseId).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

    // If the database does not exist, create a new database
    if (database == null)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the code can run in 1.6.2 but throws a null object exception in 1.6.3 or 1.7?

I cant see your code behind `IReliableReadWriteDocumentClient dbClient = GetDocumentClient()`, but I run the below code successfully whatever in 1.6.2 or 1.6.3.

```
  DocumentClient client= new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);
  var databaseName = "lilidatabasedb";
  Database database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == databaseName).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

Double check your code and you could paste more codes here to get further help.